# why m i getting NZEC Runtime error while submitting code on hacker-earth?? what should I do to remove this?

Tags: java, runtime-error

I have a code which is working perfectly on my PC but while submitting it on Hacker Earth, it is returning with NZEC Runtime error . why is this happening?
what should I do to remove this error ??

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;


class TestClass {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    int tc= Integer.parseInt(line);

    for (int i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
         Stack<Integer> player=new Stack<Integer>();
           line = br.readLine();
          int passes=Integer.parseInt(line);
          line = br.readLine();
          int ID=Integer.parseInt(line);
          player.push(ID);
          int previousplayer=ID;
          while(passes>0)
          {
             String pas_type = br.readLine();

              if(pas_type=="P")
              {
                line = br.readLine();
                int nxtplayer=Integer.parseInt(line);
               previousplayer=player.pop();
                player.push(nxtplayer);
              }
              else
              {
                player.pop();
                player.push(previousplayer);

              }
              passes--;


          }
          System.out.println("Player"+player.peek());

    }



}
```

}

Comment: what is link of the problem statement?

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/the-football-fest-6/

Comment: line = br.readLine(); int passes=Integer.parseInt(line); this statement is throwing error as it is trying to parse '10 23' even in sample case.

Comment: ok Got it ..Thank You